# Overflow or Division by Zero runtime error when using DateAdd in VBa

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting the following error when using `DateAdd` in VBA.
`Runtime error: 11 Division by Zero` or `Runtime error: 6 Overflow` (more often)

```
Dim todDate As Date
Dim currDt As Date

todDate = Format(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")

currDt = Format(DateAdd("d", 20, todDate), "mm/dd/yyyy")   ----> Runtime Error HERE
```

`todDate` is retrieved from a cell ("B6") whose format is the `short date format (mm/dd/yy)`. I have also dried using not including the `Format` function to compute currDt but no success either. Any idea why this may be?

Thank you

Comment: The Format function returns a string, not a date.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a date to the dateadd function.  Format will return a string, you were also repeating the format needlessly.  Try the below.

```
Dim todDate As Date
Dim currDt As string

todDate = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6").Value

currDt = Format(DateAdd("d", 20, todDate), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Could I get away with simply doing this `currDt =DateAdd("d", 20, todDate)` and having `Dim currDt As string`? I will have to then use `DateAdd` with `currDt` and would therefore think that it would be easier to have it as a `Date` instead of a `String`

Comment: @user3501476 well that depends on the purpose really, I would keep the date stored in a date format until i needed the user to see it, then every time you want to make a cell/messagebox equal to the date in the format mmddyyyy convert the date.  Does that make sense?  In short, keep it as a date (where the format doesn't matter) until you need to print it (where presentation is important)

Comment: @user3501476 unless I've misunderstood, are you trying to specify what format the date is already in with "Format(..."?

Comment: @user3501476 if the latter is the case, Jean-François Corbett's answer here would make some interesting reading.  Essentially read in the variable correctly and store it as a date, then print it in the form that you like using format.

Comment: I see! So any idea as to why I am getting the runtime errors when I remove all of the formats and have every variable as a `Date`?

Comment: @user3501476 that would be the problem of the Format function returning a string.  Remove this, or dim the variable as a string and youll be fine